# Кастомный toobar для фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть активити + 2 фрагмента
При работе в первом фрагменте в тулбаре есть две кнопки
При работе во втором тулбаре появляется стрелка "назад" и две кнопки должны исчезнуть
Я прочитал про кастомные тулбары для адаптеров, но к сожалению проблему не решил, так как он у меня и так кастомный, так как кнопка назад появляется только тут и цвет можно поменять только при этом фрагменте. Но я не знаю, как получить доступ к пунктам меню и как их в итоге отключить. Этот вопрос более масштабный, так как научившись делать это, я смогу в дальнейшем под каждый фрагмент реализовывать свой набор кнопок. 
Вот реализация фрагмента 2, где не должно быть кнопок, но они появляются

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detailed, container, false);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.detailed_toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_detailed);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(getArguments().getString("title"));
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Вот XML (может нужна)

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/detailed_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Я пробовал и создать отдельный XML менюшку, но не понимаю как ее заинфлейтить.

Большое спасибо за помощь. Если вопрос вам кажется не корректным, пожалуйста укажите это в комментарии, чтобы я учился и мог задавать более правильные вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, ответ отсюда с большой вероятностью может помочь

[Ответ на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196771/changing-menu-items-on-a-toolbar-menu-made-from-a-xml-layout)

Если дословно (перевод источника):

Вы можете создать меню опций, переопределив `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Вы можете создать 2 xml и инфлейтить один из них в зависимости от вашей логики.

Чтобы принудительно выполнить перерисовку меню, вы можете вызвать `invalidateOptionsMenu` во фрагменте.

Например:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if (login) {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
    } else {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.logout_menu, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

И далее снаружи изменить флаг и заставить систему перерисовать меню:

```
login = false; // or true
invalidateOptionsMenu();
// это можно сделать во фрагменте
```

Ещё момент. Надо переопределить метод `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` в активити, так как он будет вызываться каждый раз при вызове `invalidateOptionsMenu()` из фрагмента.

[Официальная документация (на русском)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus?authuser=1&hl=ru)

[Небольшой пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/46-urok-14-menju-gruppy-porjadok.html)

**Примерный код активити:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // пишем код для начального отображения меню
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // пишем код для смены иконок меню или самого меню.
    // Проверкой текущего фрагмента будет такой код
    Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    // Если у вас support Fragment созданы, используйте такую строку
    //Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if(currentFragment instanceof Fragment1) {
        // меняем меню под фрагмент1
    } else if(currentFragment instanceof Fragment2) {
        // меняем меню под фрагмент2 и так далее
    }
}
```

**Примерный код фрагмента:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // вызываем в onResume так как при смене фрагмента будет вызываться этот метод в каждом фрагменте
}
```

[ссылка: как находить текущий фрагмент](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment)

Comment: Дополню в таких случаях иногда удобнее не инфлейтить меню а создавать програмно, так все получается очевиднее , на мой взгляд.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что onCreateOptionsMenu нужно вызывать реализовывать в активити?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov да, всё верно. Он вызовется 1 раз а дальше будет запускаться `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` при каждом вызове `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Comment: Я думал, что реализация каждого меню будет находится в каждом фрагменте. Но пожалуйста подтвердите еще раз, что логика следующая: во фрагментах мы только указываем нужное меню (которое общее для всех фрагментов), а в активити мы уже производим различные проверки и сетим наши кнопки?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov я дописал примерную реализацию в ответе

Comment: Большое спасибо! Уточните пожалуйста по поводу currentFragment. В случае, когда в разметке у меня идет просто FrameLayout то, что в данном случае поможет мне указать current?

Comment: И вопрос, а реализация invalidate где происходит? Во фрагменте?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov 1) У вас идёт в разметке FrameLayout и в него вы грузите фрагменты, верно? так вот у FrameLayout должен быть id. И вы проверяете методом `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_это_id_вашего_FrameLayout_в_разметке);` фрагмент, который загружен в текущий момент в FrameLayout(он же fragment container).
2)реализация invalidate происходит во фрагменте. Там же написано "Примерный код фрагмента:". Чуть внимательнее =)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за уделенное время! Я это очень ценю. Но честно говоря, я так и упустил суть метода проверки и его цель, а так же как его связать с показом ячеек. Я сделал немного по другому, просто указав в onCreateOptionsMenu в самом фрагмента setVisible(false) и все.

Comment: @BorisRuzanov `Если вам требуется изменять меню параметров в зависимости от событий, которые возникают в течение жизненного цикла операции, сделать это можно в методе onPrepareOptionsMenu()`
У вас будут меняться фрагменты и при закрытии текущего фрагмента будет отображаться предыдущий. Если так, то у предыдущего фрагмента вызовется `onResume` метод. В моём примере, чтобы обновить меню, вызывается `invalidateOptionsMenu` и активити в зависимости от фрагмента на экране будет менять меню. **Это нужно чтоб вся работа с меню была в одном месте, а не в каждом фрагменте**

Comment: @BorisRuzanov вам надо почитать документацию(ссылка на русском в ответе) и посмотреть примеры работы с меню в интернете